# Export bash variable on die

Tags: bash

I'm writing a batch bash job with find and ffmpeg. Sometimes files die, and it's not really clear which job dies, because I have multiple files running on different machines. Is there any way to provide a last known variable at the end of a killed off script?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having every job run

```
trap 'set > /tmp/vardump-${SOME_JOB_NUMBER}-$$.sh' EXIT
```

That will make bash run this command upon exit. The command will print to that file all the variables (including functions, btw) that bash has set for that process.

`$$` is the shell's PID.

Note that this only works if bash dies in a way it can detect. It will work if bash dies with `kill <pid-of-bash>` (`SIGINT`) but not `kill -9 <pid-of-bash>` (`SIGKILL`).

Comment: don't advise people to `kill $(pgrep bash)`. it's **dangerous**.